# Multiply lower level columns with list for each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am new to pandas and have a multiIndex dataframe `df` with two level columns like this

```
        one                zero
          y         x         y         x
0  0.625695  2.149377  0.006123  0.854284
1 -1.392909  0.849853  0.005477  1.743587
```

Now I want to multiply each row of each `level=1` with a list of the same length.

So far I only managed to achieve this with something like
`df.stack(level=0).mul([1.5,2.5]).unstack(level=0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).T.sort_index().T`

The output should look like this

```
         one                    zero
           x           y           x           y
0   3.224066    1.564237    1.281426    0.015307
1   1.274779   -3.482272    2.615381    0.013692
```

I am sure there must be an easier/more elegant way to achieve this.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please include an expected output, I don't get how can a row multiplied with a list (ie I don't get what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df.mul(pd.Series({'x':1.5, 'y':2.5}), level=1)
```

Output:

```
        one                zero          
          y         x         y         x
0  1.564237  3.224066  0.015307  1.281426
1 -3.482272  1.274780  0.013692  2.615381
```

Comment: Thank you very much